# How to support Typescript and Flow simultaneously in Sublime Text

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, flowtype, sublime-text-plugin

I am working on two projects.  One uses Flow, the other Typescript.  I want to use Sublime Text for both.

I'd like to leverage Flow related packages (e.g. SublimeLinter-flow) for the Flow project, while simultaneously leveraging Typescript related packages (e.g. TypeScript) for the Typescript project.

When I install both sets of packages they clobber each other (Sublime is currently reporting Typescript errors in my Flow project).

Perhaps there's a way to make the packages project specific?  Or specific to extension type?

My only other thought (not preferred) is to use VSCode for one project and Sublime for the other...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this ST forum thread - [Ignore package per project](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/ignore-package-per-project/43905) - it looks like *tsm91* has the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to make a package project specific or active only for a specific syntax (file extension). There are [design reasons](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/ignored-packages-setting-in-project-ignored/6525/8) for this so it's not something that's likely to change.

Several years ago I had a similar problem although it was eventually resolved by a package update.

The workaround that I devised was to write a plugin to add, remove, or toggle packages in the `ignored_packages` setting. Note that the `ignored_packages` setting can not be used in project specific settings for the same design reasons linked above.

Using the `AlterIgnoredPackages` plugin below you can change your `ignored_packages` setting using a key binding when you swap between projects. I've also posted `AlterIgnoredPackages` in a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/c88a0853a952c3e37630230f5499ba7a).

```py
# Save as AlterIgnoredPackages.py in your user packages directory.
# e.g. ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/AlterIgnoredPackages.py

import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class AlterIgnoredPackagesCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):

    def run(self, add_list=[], remove_list=[], toggle_list=[]):

        preferences = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
        ignored_packages = preferences.get("ignored_packages", [])

        for package_name in add_list:
            if package_name not in ignored_packages:
                ignored_packages.append(package_name)

        for package_name in remove_list:
            if package_name in ignored_packages:
                ignored_packages.remove(package_name)

        for package_name in toggle_list:
            if package_name in ignored_packages:
                ignored_packages.remove(package_name)
            else:
                ignored_packages.append(package_name)

        preferences.set("ignored_packages", ignored_packages)
        sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")

        # Unfortunately the automatic ST reloading settings
        # message overwrites this message a bit too quickly.
        # A workaround with a timeout is in the Github Gist.
        message = "ignored_packages: " + str(ignored_packages)
        sublime.status_message(message)
```

Here are some key binding examples:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+z"],
    "command": "alter_ignored_packages",
    "args": {"add_list": ["PackageName1"], 
             "remove_list": ["PackageName2", "PackageName3"] } 
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+shift+z"],
    "command": "alter_ignored_packages",
    "args": {"toggle_list": ["PackageName"] }
},
```

Comment: Thanks @mattst.  It's good to know there's no easy way to do it.

Comment: You might consider submitting a feature request to one or both plugin authors for them to include a setting like `plugin_enabled: bool`. Then you could use project level settings to stop the plugins interfering with each other and it wouldn't matter that both plugins remained loaded.